# Why won't syntax highlighting work on some posts?

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

I cannot understand why syntax highlighting automatically works on some posts and don"t on others. Here are some examples:

**Syntax highlighting off:**

- *[How to implement swipeview QtQuick 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366283/how-to-implement-swipeview-qtquick-2-5/44414049#44414049)*
- *[Why GridView item don't wrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344779/why-gridview-item-dont-wrap)*

**Syntax highlighting on:**

- *[Qt 5.9 QML How to show ScrollBar on key up/down in material style with Flickable TextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433139/qt-5-9-qml-how-to-show-scrollbar-on-key-up-down-in-material-style-with-flickable)*
- *[How to hide a QML Window when it loses focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444257/how-to-hide-a-qml-window-when-it-loses-focus?rq=1)*

---

I know we can force language detection by inserting
`<!-- language: lang-qml -->` just before the code block, but I was wondering:

- How does the automatic language detection work?
- Where can I find the supported languages list anyway?

Comment: See the duplicate; syntax highlighting defaults are inferred from the tags. The first two questions have 0 tags with a language association, while the other two have the `qt` tag, which has `lang-cpp` configured as the default.

Comment: Note that there is no `qml` language support. You are getting the 'default' best-effort highlighting instead.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, qml does have a language association. Otherwise In the case of the last two questions, why would QtQuick be recognized by the lang-cpp parser?

Comment: It isn't. It is being treated as C++. The parser is pretty primitive.

Comment: Okay. Just to be sure, by specifying <!-- language: lang-qml --> (which seems to work), what I get is actually the default syntax highlighting?

Comment: Look at the element in the development tools of your web browser, and you'll find the `<pre class="lang-cpp prettyprint prettyprinted">` tag wrapping it. Note the `lang-cpp` class.

Comment: Yes, unrecognised `lang-...` language tags are handled as if you used `lang-default`.

Comment: Note that (as documented in the FAQ I duped you to) you can check the tag wiki (linked as `info`, or `learn more`, depending on where you are) lists the highlighting language if one is set. Check the [`qt` info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/qt/info) (scroll to the bottom) with the [`qml` info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/qml/info).

Comment: And how would you add a highlighting language for the qml tag? Seems to me that the default highlighting does a pretty decent work, so why not set it as qml default?